# Why there are only 75 visible characters in Intellij Idea's embedded terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, console, visibility

When I use Idea's embedded command prompt in the tools window I can only see 75 characters. The chars are there but they are not visible:

C:>echo "This is the sentence I want to show you but I get only 75 characters h
"This is the sentence I want to show you but I get only 75 characters here"

Neither have I found any setting for this, nor have I found someone with the same problem by googling

Idea version is 13.1.13 on Windows 7 with jdk 1.7x

Outside idea, cmd.exe's (Version 6.1.7601) configuration is not limiting anything to 75

Comment: That's weird. Do you have any profile settings (.profile) that may be causing it? In the terminal, type `ls -GAFaoh` (without the quotes).

Comment: You could do that with gnuwin or cygwin, but this is a windows prompt

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a known bug: [IDEA-117552 Terminal output truncated to 80 symbols](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552)

Happens on my system, too (JDK 1.7, Windows 7, 32bit).

If line length matters (not for me), you can set the terminal floating and reduce its horizontal size. Then it works.

[image]

Comment: Moreover, if you set it back as not floating, it keeps on working

Comment: For me, it does not seem to work when I set it back. But the floating mode trick did make it work! (How can they still haven't fixed this major bug?!)

Answer (score 84):

**Notice:** since IDEA 2016.3.2 this breaks the terminal and is not required anymore. So just delete it when you update to a version it cannot create the Terminal.

For windows change the terminal shell path (File->Settings->Tools->Terminal) from `cmd.exe` to:

```
cmd.exe "/K mode con:cols=500 lines=9999&cmd.exe"
```

or if using the bash for windows subsystem:

```
cmd.exe "/K set LINES=9999&C:\windows\system32\bash.exe"
```

as described in the bug description (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552)

Edit: wrap /K in quotes as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This only helps

Comment: This answer definitely made the bug alter its behavior, but in WebStorm 8.0.4 it doesn't solve the issue, just makes the line break in different places. What a mess, I won't be upgrading. Can't believe how long this bug has been open.

Comment: Works, but pay attention - I had to wrap `cmd.exe` in **quotes**, i.e `"cmd.exe" /K "mode con:cols=500 lines=9999&cmd.exe"`, otherwise you get the annoying `java.io.IOEXception:couldn't create PTY` error.

Comment: Why is this still not fixed after 2+ years?

Comment: It works for terminal window but what about run ? there I have still 75 cols output from run command.

Comment: what about macos solution ? I am facing the same issue in mac env too

Comment: @Alupotha The question here was meant for windows. I don't use MacOS so I can't really say how this should be. I think you should ask the question specifically for mac and link to this question. That way you might get an answer really fast.

Comment: @ Alupotha Did u find an answer for Run? Its driving me nuts that limit!