# Terminal on Android studio truncates output

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, terminal, command-line-interface

As shown in the below screenshot taken from Android studio's terminal window, it truncates text beyond a point (rectangle in white color). This happens even when I type in something. The text is present, but doesn't show up. What to do for resolving this?

[image: Android studio's terminal window truncated text]

Answer (score 1):

This fixes various Win10/Android studio 'terminal' oddities:

*In Windows*
RUN the old 'DOS console' ie **command prompt** -  cmd.exe
[e.g. press **win+r** then type **cmd.exe**]
Right click logo (top left corner)
Click *properties*
Click *Options* folder
Tick  *Use legacy console* checkbox
Click OK

*In Android Studio*
Close and re-open the terminal session

*Finally*
If you are still having problems, just use use the windows command prompt instead!
OR
check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32500513/2376004) answer